# jquery inside a loop console log the value

Tags: jquery

Trying to code a validation function but for the life of me I can't grab the inputs values!

It's a loop and I want to console log the current input value, how can I do that?

```
function is_empty() {
    for (var i=0; i < $('form input').length; i++) {
        console.log($('form input')[i]);
        console.log($('form input')[i].val);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this in the console:

first line: `<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..">`

second line: `undefined`

How can I get the values?

Thanks..

Comment: What is $('form input'), if its a class you are missing . if its id you must use # Example: $('.form .input') or $('#form')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$(...)[i]`, you're accessing the *underlying element*, not a jQuery collection that contains that element. `.val()` is a method on a jQuery collection (note the parentheses - it's a *function*, so you have to call it). On an ordinary element, you should use `.value` to retrieve the associated value:

```
console.log($('form input')[i].value);
```

Or, if you want to use the jQuery, method, use `eq` to transform the collection of matched elements to a collection containing only the element at that index, and then call `.val()`:

```
console.log($('form input').eq(i).val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be .val() instead of val

Answer (score 0):

Use .**val()** not .**val**

```
console.log($('form input')[i].val());
```